# How to troubleshoot a LDAP error 53 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM)?

Tags: centos, ldap, active-directory

I am trying to make a CentOS 7 server join an AD, but it results in an error:

> AD LDAP ERROR: 53 (Server is unwilling to perform): 0000216D: SvcErr: DSID-031A1241, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0

Command run:

```
[root@myserver ~]# realm join --user='dr@example.org' --computer-ou=OU=ABC,OU=Servers,OU=ACME,OU=Units,DC=example,DC=org example.org
Password for dr@example.org:
See: journalctl REALMD_OPERATION=r12682208.2790
realm: Couldn't join realm: Joining the domain example.org failed

[root@myserver ~]# journalctl REALMD_OPERATION=r12682208.2790 --no-pager
-- Logs begin at Mon 2022-04-25 14:28:51 CEST, end at Tue 2022-04-26 13:51:12 CEST. --
Apr 26 13:49:01 myserver.example.org realmd[2794]:  * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.example.org
Apr 26 13:49:01 myserver.example.org realmd[2794]:  * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 10.1.1.1
Apr 26 13:49:01 myserver.example.org realmd[2794]:  * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 10.2.2.2
Apr 26 13:49:01 myserver.example.org realmd[2794]:  * Successfully discovered: example.org
Apr 26 13:49:08 myserver.example.org realmd[2794]:  * Required files: /usr/sbin/oddjobd, /usr/libexec/oddjob/mkhomedir, /usr/sbin/sssd, /usr/bin/net
Apr 26 13:49:08 myserver.example.org realmd[2794]:  * LANG=C LOGNAME=root /usr/bin/net -s /var/cache/realmd/realmd-smb-conf.HGKCL1 -U dr@example.org ads join example.org createcomputer=Units/ACME/Servers/ABC
Apr 26 13:49:09 myserver.example.org realmd[2794]: Enter dr@example.org's password:ads_print_error: AD LDAP ERROR: 53 (Server is unwilling to perform): 0000216D: SvcErr: DSID-031A1241, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0
Apr 26 13:49:09 myserver.example.org realmd[2794]:
Apr 26 13:49:09 myserver.example.org realmd[2794]:
Apr 26 13:49:09 myserver.example.org realmd[2794]: Failed to join domain: failed to precreate account in ou ou=ABC,ou=Servers,ou=ACME,ou=Units,dc=example,dc=org: Server is unwilling to perform
Apr 26 13:49:09 myserver.example.org realmd[2794]:  ! Joining the domain example.org failed
```

The account used has the right to add a server to the domain. (Tested on the MS Windows AD.)

The `--verbose` option of `realm` doesn't show any additional useful information.

How can I find the source of the issue?

Comment: IDK, but I suspect it's refusing the `LOGNAME=root` part of your request. Check the logs on the server.

Comment: Install `wireshark` and you can watch the packets go back and forth.

Comment: Logically you cannot assert both "I don't understand what is happening" and "`--verbose` doesn't show additional useful information...".

Comment: @waltinator I'd tend to disagree. I can know the phase of the moon isn't relevant to my problem and I can know that my breakfast wasn't relevant without knowing the cause of my problem; I can surely make a reasonable assessment that other things are unrelated also.  In context I'd be pretty confident the OP's assessment is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are encountering is coming from the Active Directory server itself.  So the verbose error message, if it exists, is likely to be in the "Event Log" on the Active Directory server.

### The root cause of your error:

This looks like a configuration issue on your AD server.  The "system error code" `0000216D` is documented [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--8200-8999-)<sup>1</sup>:

> ERROR_DS_MACHINE_ACCOUNT_QUOTA_EXCEEDED
>
> 8557 (0x216D)
>
> Your computer could not be joined to the domain. You have exceeded the maximum number of computer accounts you are allowed to create in this domain. Contact your system administrator to have this limit reset or increased.

AD server is configured, by default, to allow only 10 machines (*per user?*) to join the domain.  Documented [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-ms-ds-machineaccountquota):

> MS-DS-Machine-Account-Quota attribute
>
> The number of computer accounts that a user is allowed to create in a domain.

This can be reconfigured.

I'm not an MS Windows export so I can't easily tell you how to reconfigure this... but there are numerous examples on the internet.  You can search for the above text on google or just try this one:

- https://niallbrady.com/2019/02/21/how-to-fix-exceeded-the-maximum-number-of-computer-accounts-allowed-to-create-in-this-domain/

### How to troubleshoot an LDAP error

In LDAP, most things are conveyed by numbers and [OID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_identifier)s.  Though with an error message like yours it can be tricky to know which number to search for:

```
AD LDAP ERROR: 53 (Server is unwilling to perform): 0000216D: SvcErr: DSID-031A1241, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0
```

There are four numbers above to search for:

- `53` - references "Server is unwilling to perform" - This is too generic to find more useful information.
- `0000216D` - looks like the system error code which are well documented [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes)
- `DSID-031A1241` - I can find no good reference to the DSID's meaning.  They appear to go with AD errors, but don't seem to be documented.
- `5003` - references problem WILL_NOT_PERFORM - This is too generic to find more useful information.

---

<sup>1</sup>*Thanks to Simon Ren for the direction in his answer [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/60cdeb62-ecab-4ecc-a4f4-28e8a596fe8f/machine-is-not-joining-to-domain-during-osd?forum=ConfigMgrCBOSD)*